# Datatable Sorting, Pagination and Search Hidden for PHP MYSQL Search Result

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatables

I cant get Sort icons, pagination buttons, Search Form jQuery datatables Work for PHP MYSQL Dynamic Data.

I can see Sort icon, `Next` and `Previous` button and Search form  when there is no record displayed  the problem is when there is dynamic data coming from MYSQL table

HTML part of DataTables

```
   <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Brand Name</th>
                                        <th>Size</th>
                                        <th>SW</th>
                                        <th>OD</th>


                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                              <tbody>
```

//Here is PHP Code i used to display the record

```
   $record = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY Manufacturer");
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($record)) {
   if($row['RC']!="" && $row['SW']!="")
     {
      if($ag=="" && $size1=="" && $size=="" && $lcc=="" && $scc=="" && $smallsw==""  && $largesw=="" && $smallrc=="" && $largerc=="" && $txtsize=="" && $small== "" && $large == "")  
     {
     }

     elseif ($row['Tread_Design']==$R1W) 
        {    
      echo "<tr>";


                        //echo "<td style=' width:300px;text-align:left; padding-left: 10px;vertical-align: middle;'>";echo $row['Manufacturer'];echo"</td>";
                        echo "<td style=' width:150px;  text-align:left; padding: 10px;vertical-align: middle;'>";echo $row['Brand_Name'];echo"</td>";
                        echo "<td style='width:110px;  text-align:left; vertical-align: middle;'>";echo $row['Tire_Size'];"</td>";
                        echo "<td style='width:100px;  text-align:left; vertical-align: middle;'>";echo $row['SW'];"</td>"; 
                        echo "<td style='width:100px; text-align:left;vertical-align: middle;'>";echo $row['OD'];"</td>";

    echo '</tr>';
```

}
}......

And Here is the JS Code

```
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            bPaginate: true,

      });
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: Does that page stand up to being passed through a HTML validator - I'm wondering what you mean by Dynamic as well...  You could use `ssp.class.php` from the site to get DataTables to populate your table for you: https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html

Comment: Dynamic - The Data coming from MYSQL Table

Comment: So to confirm: Each time your PHP above runs you generate a new table and the initialise it? You are closing your `tbody` and `table` after you do your `while` loop aren't you? Could you paste your generated HTML into a JSFiddle and then run try to create a DataTable?